# The Pentomino Snake

Tags: tiling, polyomino

The premise of the puzzle is quite simple. Here's how to set it up.

> 1. Draw a 5x5 grid of squares.
> 2. Write the number 1 in the middle.
> 3. Make a "snake" of numbers up to 25 so that each number is orthogonal from the previous number AND the next number.
> 4. Divide the grid into the pentominoes formed by the numbers 1-5, 6-10, 11-15, 16-20, and 21-25.
> 5. If no two of the pentominoes are the same when rotated or reflected, you win. If two or more are, then you lose.

Example:

[image: sorry for bad quality]

This fails because 6-10 and 11-15 are the same, as are 16-20 and 21-25.

**Is it possible to win this game? If your answer is no, prove it. If your answer is yes, give an example.**

(I don't quite know how to tag this, feel free to edit some other tags in.)

Comment: I don't understand `each number is orthogonal from the previous number AND the next number.` Do you simply mean that `n` should be connected to `n-1` and `n+1`, no matter in which direction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand the game correctly,

> 21,22,23,24,25
> 20,11,10, 9, 8
> 19,12, 1, 2, 7
> 18,13,14, 3, 6
> 17,16,15, 4, 5

Comment: I had a rotation of this. Well done!

Answer (score 7):

I guess, I'm too late, but I propose

> [[image: A possible way]1]

Comment: Nice!  And looks "prettier" than mine!